# Where's the Powershell (Core) that installed from Windows Store located?

Tags: powershell, windows-store-app

I installed Powershell from Windows Store. I would like to use that as my terminal in VS Code, but it can't find the PS.

Where's the Powershell located?

Comment: PowerShell is built into Windows and does not need installation. I have no idea what you have installed from the Microsoft Store. You will find `Windows PowerShell` inside the Start Menu.

Comment: @harrymc PowerShell Core needs installation though. @Farid try to find it by running this command in any of your PowerShells `get-appxpackage | ? Name -like '*PowerShell*'` it should tell you where it is installed in the InstallLocation property. However, I'd advise you to install it via .msi or chocolatey

Comment: @harrymc - ps7+ [once known as ps core] _is faster and has MANY benefits over ps5.1 at this time. if you are not yet aware of those benefits, please do a search on `why powershell 7`. [*grin*]

Comment: i did not install from the MSStore ... i installed via the MSI so that i could fully control the installation. however, my understanding is that ps6 & ps7 - when installed from the MSStore - end up in the USER profile, not in the more sensible `C:\Program Files` location.

Comment: I added an answer, which I hope fits your case.

Comment: "PowerShell Core is only required for ARM devices." - **This is absolutely false.**  PowerShell Core is the "current" version of PowerShell.  PowerShell 5.1 is actually considered legacy and currently being developed.

Comment: @SimonS Thank you! Exactly what I needed. Found the location now :)

Comment: @Farid - Unless you update Visual Studio Code it won't matter if you know the location.  Visual Studio Code won't be able to discover that location.  Your issue was fixed with a software patch back in January to Visual Studio Code.

Comment: My VS Code is always updated :) I should clarify, that the issue actually comes because I had PS installed thru .msi previously. I uninstalled that and installed from Store, and then VS couldn't find my new PS location (I'm guessing it's still looking for the old .msi's PS location). I've pointed the PS (Store version) location to VS Code.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 11 Pro 22H2, the executable can be found at:
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.PowerShell_8wekyb3d8bbwe\pwsh.exe`

The numbers there in the folder name might be different for your installation.

If you open `%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\` in explorer and look for a folder that starts with `Microsoft.PowerShell` you should be able to locate the folder with the executable in it.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#PSHOME) the installation path is stored in variable $PSHOME. It can be queried in Powershell with command

`$PSHOME`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1175841)

Answer (score 1):

> Where's the PowerShell 7 located?

If you installed Power Shell 7 from an MSI, then a PowerShell 7 folder, exists in your Program Files directory. If you installed it from the Microsoft Store, it will exist within a directory, contained in the WindowsApps directory.

[According to a list of tasks the VS Code team worked on last year, the current version of Visual Studio Code, automatically detects PowerShell 7 from the Microsoft Store.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112419), If it's not being automatically detected you should simply update Visual Studio Code to the current version.

In order for Visual Studio Code to discover Power Shell 7 installed from the Microsoft Store you must be running at least Visual Studio Code January 2021 (1.53)

Source: [January 2021 (version 1.53)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53)

Comment: Ahh, that's where I messed up. Initially I installed from .msi, then I uninstalled it and moved to Store version (for easier update).

Answer (score 0):

You will find the answer in the article
[Using PowerShell 7 in VS Code](https://rnelson0.com/2020/03/05/using-powershell-7-in-vs-code/).

After installing PowerShell 7 via the `.msi` installer,
the last steps are:

- Select Edit in `settings.json` and add this text
  and save the file:

  ```
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
  ```

  (use the correct path if you installed to a non-default location.)
- Run `notepad $profile` and copy the contents for later.
- Restart VS Code and you should have a uncustomized
  PowerShell 7 prompt.

The following is for copying your old profile into the new one:

- Run `notepad $profile`
- Paste your old profile
- Save and exit
- Restart VS Code

The above article contains more details with screenshots.

Comment: @Ramhound: That's correct. In the poster's case, it was finally commented that this is an `.msi` install.

Comment: @Ramhound: The poster tried both installations. I added the context in my answer to complete this post.